# Finding USA's roads key attributes for OpenStreetMap

Tags: openstreetmap

I understand that most of the data in OSM for USA is coming from TIGER. It seems that this doesn't have complete road key attributes such as speed limit, maximum weight, allowed / restricted turns, lane change etc.
I found that some state level DOT do have public datasets available for the roads within their jurisdiction, however some states don't have that. I wonder if the OSM community knows if the data already available at these state DOT's was loaded in the OSM?

Please also let me know if there was a netter place to ask this question?

Many thanks,

It is stated in the OSM webpage as well as in other GIS blogs that OSM doesn't have much data on key attributes of roads ie truck restrictions, however some DOT do have data on that.
In OSM pages it wasn't clear if that data was loaded.

Comment: Why don't you ask the OSM community directly about this? https://community.openstreetmap.org/

Comment: You can also search on the GIS exchange: https://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Cross-post: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/449545/usa-road-restrictions-in-osm-from-public-state-datasets

Answer (score 1):

There's been an awful lot of discussion about data imports, especially within the USA, over the years.  I suspect that if data is available and hasn't been imported into OSM it's for one of two reasons:

- the quality isn't very good
- the licence isn't compatible

The relevant OSM wiki page that explains what would someone suggesting a new import need to do is [here](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Import/Guidelines).  With regard to the "[community buy-in](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Import/Guidelines#Step_2_-_Community_Buy-in)" step, I'd suggest contacting the OSM USA community in the first instance via the [forum](https://community.openstreetmap.org/c/communities/us/78), [mailing list](https://lists.openstreetmap.org/listinfo/talk-us) or OSM US' [slack workspace](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/List_of_OSM_centric_Slack_workspaces#Slack_workspaces).